# Normalize Agilent dataset

Tags: r

I have an Agilent dataset, I am trying to read and normalize it. I used the code below but I am getting an Error :

```
library(limma)
targets <- readTargets("targets1.txt", row.names=1,sep ="")
x <- read.maimages(targets$Filename,source="agilent",green.only=TRUE)
```

The error is: `can not open connection`. In addition: `can not open File RNA no such file or directory`

Comment: Make sure your current working directory (`getwd()`) is the same that the file is in. Or instead use the full file path, e.g. `C:/Users/Foo/Documents/targets1.txt`.

Comment: @molx yes the setwd() is correct

Comment: ...and that the files indicated in targets.txt are correct -- it looks like it's looking for a 'file' 'RNA' or maybe 'File RNA', which is likely not correct. Consider asking questions about Bioconductor packages on the Bioconductor [support site](https://support.bioconductor.org).

Comment: @Martin Recreate The target file and i used tab to separate the content. is there any standard for target file format ?

Comment: @Azize -- I don't have anything more magical than the help pages `?readTargets`, `?read.maimages` and the advice on the help pages to read the (excellent) vignette. You're only using the `Filename` column of targets; why not add the output of `targets$Filename` to your question?

Comment: @Martin-- Thank you for your advice, its work now , but  please when i change the green.only = TRUE  to  red.only=TRUE  the code does not work ?  the data is is single channel and they used cy3 , iam new to agilent so i am confused also with result there  is column and row that come out after normalizing and producing CSV file  ? please need help